# Kotlin - sort a map where value is a List

Tags: sorting, dictionary, kotlin

I have a `MutableMap<String, List<CustomObject>>` and I'm trying to sort the map by a date field in the CustomObject. I tried something like this

```
val unsortedMap: MutableMap<String, List<CustomObject>> // data already populated
val sortedMap: MutableMap<String, List<CustomObject>> = LinkedHashMap()
unsortedMap.entries.sortedBy { s -> s.value.sortedBy { t -> t.dateField } }.forEach { it2 -> sortedMap[it2.key] = it2.value }
```

but I get a `Type mismatch. Required: Comparable<List<CustomObject>> Found: List<CustomObject>` in the block that sorts by `dateField`. Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to include more code.  I don't see the definition of `eventsMap`.  Also, please don't summarize error messages ("a type mismatch error")... instead include the entire error message.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you can reliably use a List as a key to a MutableMap in Kotlin.  I suspect that there is a better way of doing what you're trying.  Can you describe your entire problem?

Comment: @JoelFan thank you for replying. II've edited the question to include more information. I changed the code to use the String as the key.                                                             I have a Map whose key is a String and value is a list of custom data object. I want to sort the map with respect to the date field in the custom data object. This is my first kotlin project and I don't see a way to sort the map when the value is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
sortedBy { s -> s.value.sortedBy { t -> t.dateField } }
```

The outer `sortedBy` needs the lambda to define something to allow it to compare different `List<CustomObject>`. However, you are "returning" just `s.value.sortedBy { ... }`. That is, you're returning a `List<CustomObject>` here, not something that can *compare* lists of custom objects.

If you want to sort your map by the earliest of all `dateField`s in each list, then you  will want something like this:

```
sortedBy { s -> s.value.sortedBy { t -> t.dateField }.first().dateField }
```

This will first sort your list of objects by their `dateField`, and then extract the `dateField` from the first item in the list, and use that for comparison.

It turns out that sorting and then taking the first item is common enough that there's a function to simplify it:

```
sortedBy { s -> s.value.minBy { t -> t.dateField }!!.dateField }
```